# Rails - Convert string to time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm  trying to parse these string into time: `"3 on Jun 20"`, `"Jun 20 at 3"`, `"Jun 20 at 300"`.

Using `DateTime.parse` didnt parse `"3"`, `"300"` into `"3:00 AM"`, it just returns `Wed, 20 Jun 2018 00:00:00 +0000`.

Anyone has any idea to parse these integer into time?

Comment: BTW, according to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#class-DateTime-label-When+should+you+use+DateTime+and+when+should+you+use+Time-3F), `DateTime` should be used when dealing with historic dates. For recent dates, `Time` is the preferred class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic), a *"natural language date/time parser"*:

```
require 'chronic'

Chronic.parse('3 on Jun 20')    #=> 2018-06-20 15:00:00 +0200
Chronic.parse('Jun 20 at 3')    #=> 2018-06-20 15:00:00 +0200
Chronic.parse('Jun 20 at 300')  #=> 2018-06-20 15:00:00 +0200
```

Answer (score 4):

Just out of curiosity, trying to reinvent `chronic` in 4 LOCs :)

```
["3 on Jun 20", "Jun 20 at 3", "Jun 20 at 300"].map do |dt|
  d, t = dt.split(/\s+at\s+/i)
  t, d = dt.split(/\s+on\s+/i) unless t
  return [dt] unless t && d

  t = t[0..-3] + (t[-2..-1] ? ":" << t[-2..-1] : t[/.{,2}\z/] + ":00")
  [d, t] # [["Jun 20", "3:00"], ["Jun 20", "3:00"], ["Jun 20", "3:00"]]
end.map { |dt| DateTime.parse dt.join ' ' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use strptime to parse a custom format:

```
DateTime.strptime("3 on Jun 20", "%H on %b %d")
```

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime

Comment: That is hardly applied to _both_ inputs specified.

Comment: This is an example for one format. You have to define a "template" string for each format.

Comment: @Alexis if `strptime` fails to match the pattern, it raises an `ArgumentError`. Are you suggesting to `rescue` it in order to try the next one?

Comment: Yes, or using `_strptime` which returns a hash / nil instead of a Date. At least it avoids to write a rescue with an empty block (which can be considered as a code smell).